# webpage isn't getting displayed in Task Module MS Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a webpage that needs to be displayed in Task Module in MS Teams, I have developed a solution using bot framework v4. Whenever I try to invoke a task module I get blank screen. I have also added bot URL to valid domains list.

[image]

Here is app manifest (I have changed azure website link for confidentiality.)

````
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.5",
    "version": "1.5.0",
    "id": "b7b71f97-2521-4e66-b359-9be61930cbdb",
    "packageName": "net.azurewebsites.myweb",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Tech Mahindra ",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.techx.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.techx.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.techx.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "techx QT",
        "full": "techx bot"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "This is techx patient tracker.",
        "full": "This application is still in development and any information shown here is just demonstartion purpose."
    },
    "accentColor": "#8B8B8B",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "3b3f1550-eee6-4c56-91c5-XXXXXXXXX",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal"
            ],
            "commandLists": [
                {
                    "scopes": [
                        "team"
                    ],
                    "commands": [
                        {
                            "title": "task",
                            "description": "task for testing task module"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "supportsFiles": true,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "myweb.azurewebsites.net"
    ]
}```


***WebPage(PFRPDetailsForm.cshtml) code***

   <html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding-left: 4px;
            padding-right: 4px;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Microsoft Teams Task Module Tester - Custom Form</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="@("https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/teams-js@1.6.0/dist/MicrosoftTeams.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        microsoftTeams.initialize();

        function validateForm() {

            microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask("just for demo");
            return true;
        }
    </script>

    <div class="surface theme-light">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="font-semibold font-title">Patient Registration Form:</div>
                <form method="POST" id="customerForm" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
                    <div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div><label for="fname">First Name: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="fname" type="text"  name="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div><label for="mname">Middle Name: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="mname" type="text"  name="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div><label for="lname">Last Name: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="mname" type="text"  name="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div><label for="sex">SEX : </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="fname" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div><label for="nationality">Nationality: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="fname" type="text"  name="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;"></div><label for="uid">UID: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="mname" type="text" name="name" tabindex="1" autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div><label for="email">Email: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="email" type="email" placeholder="name@email.com" name="email" tabindex="2">
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div><label for="favoriteBook">Primary Phone Number: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="pphonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Phone 1" name="phonenumber" tabindex="3">
                        <div class="form-group form-field-input" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></div><label for="pw">Secoundary Phone Number: </label><input class="form-control input-field" id="sphonenumber" type="text" placeholder="Phone 2" name="sphonenumber" tabindex="4">
                        <button class="btn button-primary" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" type="submit" tabindex="5">Next</button>
                        <button class="btn button-primary" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" type="submit" tabindex="5">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is related, but here's a possible suggestion - when you invoke a Task Module from a Messaging Extension, there's an option to specify a domain there, that's used for this. Perhaps that section needs to be filled in your manifest, even without an actual Message Extension ("Compose Extension" registred). Have a look at the schema [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#composeextensions)

part of it below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  ...
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "%MICROSOFT-APP-ID-REGISTERED-WITH-BOT-FRAMEWORK%",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [
        ...
      ],
      "messageHandlers": [
        {
          "type" : "link",
          "value" : {
            "domains" : [
              "mysite.someplace.com",
              "othersite.someplace.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
```

...
      ],
      "validDomains": [
         "contoso.com",
         "mysite.someplace.com",
         "othersite.someplace.com"
      ]
    })

Comment: I added but issue still persists :(

Comment: I have removed <form> tag in .cshtml page and I am able to see all input and label labels. So, the above answer is correct, but I am still unable to understand why is <form> not rendering all the elements  :(

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hilton